# HTML 3 columns, fixed header and side divs, scrolling middle inside a 940px container

Tags: html, css

I'm reusing some working HTML that does the job I need to, but on a page that has width 100%.

My current needs require to have a **centered div container with a fixed width of 940px**.
The code I've found does NOT work when giving a max width of 940px.

What am I missing here in order to make this work on a container of 940px?

```
<div class='wrap'>              <-- width 100%
  <div class='container'>       <-- width 940px

      <div class='head'>Header</div>
      <div class='bodywrap'>
        <div class='left'>left</div>
        <div class='right'>right</div>
        <div class='center'>center</div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [**JS-Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r7c1f5nc/) where you will find the **"container"** div that supposed to enforce a 940px width, centered.

Also on re-sizing the center div (the one that supposed to scroll), should re-size too. Right now it seems that the middle div gets covered by the right div, and that's NOT what we want.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? The way I see it currently is that your center div is being overlaid by the left and right. Are you trying to have a left/right sidebar at a fixed with and then the centered div should take up the rest of the space of the 940? What would you like it to look like when the browser window is less than 940px wide? You either force a consistent 940px container, causing horizontal scrolling or you can have sidebars be a percentage width (not position fixed, which takes them out of the flow of the document).

Comment: Hi Alex ...on bootstrap you get a container that has 940px for sites like Facebook that you do NOT want to expand in width. So the ideal goal is to have the TOP header fixed and below, the 2 side columns fixed while the center one ...I will add infinite scrolling. The JS-Fiddler works but it's not 940px width enforced an that causes me problems. I'm trying to find out how to make it work within a 940px centered 'container'

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/r7c1f5nc/13/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Does that work (like in Facebook) so that the width is 940px MAX?

Comment: you can set media query for max-width less than

Comment: I tried enforcing that on the container css class but it does not seems to work. That's my main problem, I really don't understand why it's not working.  BTW, love that calc(100%-400px)  :--)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I have seen this css for middling the container.

```
.container {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```